# 'Fluttertoast' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Will be removed in further release

Tags: android, ios, flutter, cross-platform, toast

I was using Flutter Toast https://pub.dev/packages/fluttertoast in my project and it was working fine a week ago, today i've opened my project and updates the flutter and dart and now it is showing mw that Flutter Toast is deprecated and try replacing the use of the deprecated member with the replacement.dart(deprecated_member_use). i don't know what to do? is there any recommended library to show toasts in flutter which is using on scalable applications or how do i fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the package's [API docs,](https://pub.dev/documentation/fluttertoast/latest/fluttertoast/fluttertoast-library.html) you just have to replace `Fluttertoast` with `FlutterToast` (note the change with the capital T) and the `showToast` method parameters too have been changed.

Refer to the [How To Use](https://pub.dev/packages/fluttertoast#how-to-use) for more details and snippet

Comment: Not working with Caps T, can you please mention which version you are using?

Comment: For this plugin there is [Toast with BuildContext](https://pub.dev/packages/fluttertoast#toast-with-buildcontext-all-platforms), and here's the class naming`FToast fToast;`  .. where you have to set context after instantiated